# HTML structure spoils when use substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, substring

I have following as a Description field.

```
<div>
      <p>this is a list</p>
      <div style="color:red;">description</div>
      <ul>
           <li>one</li>
           <li>two</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Now we have a constrain to show only 20 characters in description. but if I do `substring` to extract desired string, some of HTML tags start, but do not complete. So the 'view' loses its 'form', and spoil parent divs.

I want to extract only 20 chars without changing its form and without spoiling parent div's form.

please refere [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYvJG/) - here I have used 80 chars, to include divs and p tags

Comment: please show your jquery

Comment: please provide some jQuery code or jsFiddle

Comment: `if(description.length>20){description=description.substring(0,20)}` here description text would have everything including div, ul, li, p , etc

Comment: please see my modified question

Comment: OK, so which parts of the HTML do you need to keep? If it were up to me, I'd do away with all the markup and only keep the text. But that should be your choice, not ours.

Comment: Markup is necessary, what my final solution if nothing works is put a max height for the div and toggle it's size for more and less.